# Transform String to Object using jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I will get a JSON in the following format

```
"address":
{
   "type": "Temporary"
}
```

Following is the Address class.

```
class Address
{
    AddressType type;
    public Address(AddressType type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
}

class AddressType
{
    private String type;
    public AddressType(String type)
    {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

If Address.java had type as String, it would have been easier to transform from `JSON` to Address object. But I am not sure how I can transform the `JSON` to Address object where "type" will get transformed to `AddressType` object. I will use Jackson library. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

For AddressType itself, that should work just as it is, since Jackson will convert a string to an object where the object has a public constructor taking a single string.

For serialization, you may want to annotate the type field or getType method with @JsonValue to perform the reverse transformation.

To have the Address constructor called with the type given, you need the @JsonCreator annotation on the constructor, and @JsonProperty annotations on its parameters:

```
@JsonCreator
public Address(@JsonProperty("type") AddressType type) { ... }
```